# How to turn off calling help on F1?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am playing ADOM right now and under F1 button there is very aggressive tactic, which is extremaly useful when you are fighting on distance. Right now I can't use it, because help dialog pops up. How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Launch System → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Locate the line that says "Launch help browser"
3. Click where it says "F1"
4. Hit the Backspace key.
5. It should now say "Disabled"

Comment: Yeah, it was already disabled (I guess I must have disabled it manually in the console). But the window still appears. There is no F1 in keyboard shortcuts and yet help pop ups still.

Comment: Try mapping F1 to "Toggle magnifier" under Accessibility in Keyboard Shortcuts, then unmap "Toggle magnifier" (it should say "Disabled").

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1317325

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.