# Keyboard Shortcut not Appearing in Keyboard

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, minecraft, lock, function-keys

I'm trying to play Minecraft (A video game) that makes use of <kbd>F3</kbd>. However, I'm on a laptop which requires you to hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd> in order for a F# key to be registered. The problem is that Ubuntu registers <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> as the lock keyboard shortcut. How can I turn this behavior off? Also, the shortcut isn't appearing in Keyboard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was having the same problem with Minecraft. Just as a hunch, I tried pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> without <kbd>Fn</kbd> and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is some background info that could help.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts#Replacing_keys_with_other_keys)

Check out the section on replacing shortcut keys. It's near the bottom. You can use xbindkeys to set hot-keys.  Here's how:

Install xbindkeys with:
`sudo apt-get install xbindkeys`.

Create a default config file with:
`xbindkeys --defaults > /home/your-user-name/.xbindkeysrc`

Install the GUI for xbindkeys with:
`sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config`

The xvkbd utility must also be installed:
`sudo apt-get install xvkbd`

Next, bring up "Run Application" and type
`xbindkeys` and `xbindkeys-config`

If you want to override the system hot-keys already in effect, you need to install xmacro:
`sudo apt-get install xmacro`

Start xmacro with `xmacroec :0.0`
After giving a key that will allow you to quit xmacro, you can press the key(s) you want to know the code for.  You can then use xbindkeys to override the system hot-keys that are bothering you.

[Here is the home page for xbindkeys.](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html)

This may help as well :
[Here is a tutorial for turning off a shortcut.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2399/how-to-turn-off-calling-help-on-f1)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.